# Delete item in cart after customer logged in

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer, login, cart-items

I need to delete an item in cart after customer loggend in a scratch like this:

```
foreach($items as $item){
   if(condition == true){
    $item->delete();
   }
}
```

the problem is i don't know which event will trigger the observer, and get cart items and delete it from observer